# What do you call a group consisting of stocks, etfs, and futures?

Tags: futures, sec, terminology

In the command line interface to my program, the user can create a basket of stocks, etfs, or futures by saying:

> basket = stocks
>
> basket = etfs
>    basket = futures
>   basket = options

But I want to make a pre-combined basket, consisting of stocks, etfs and futures.  Yes, I could make the user enter:

basket = stocks,etfs,futures

But is there a single word appropriate for this predefined basket? "Securities" doesn't include etfs and futures.

Is there an appropriate word?

Comment: "Delta One" Portfolio ?

Comment: Why ets and futs are not securities?

Comment: futes are not securities because regulated by CFTC, but ETF's are securities and regulated by SEC

Comment: Agree with @AlexC. "delta one" is the name that traders will use most of the time.

Comment: Equity instruments

Comment: The market? Investment vehicles? Financial instruments?

Answer (score 1):

These are 'delta one' products, referring to the greek, i.e. a 1-to-1 change in the product's price given a change in the underlying.

Answer (score 0):

I would call these "constituents".